# How to program a function to return values on some sort of probability?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, probability

This question arose to me while I was playing FIFA.

Assumingly, they programmed a complex function which includes all the factors like shooting skills, distance, shot power etc. to calculate the probability that the shot hits the target. How would they have programmed something that the goal happens according to that probability?

In other words, like a function **X()** has the probability that it return **1** 89% and **0** 11%. How would I program it so that it returns 1 (approximately) 89 times in 100 trials?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generate a [uniformly-distributed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_%28continuous%29) random number between `0` and `1`, and return `true` if the number is less than the desired probability (`0.89`).

For example, in [IPython](http://ipython.org/):

```py
In [13]: from random import random

In [14]: vals = [random() < 0.89 for i in range(10000)]

In [15]: sum(vals)
Out[15]: 8956
```

In this realisation, 8956 out of the 10000 boolean outcomes are `true`. If we repeat the experiment, the number will vary around 8900.

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking about random numbers and modulus operator. Just could think it could be so simple. :)

Comment: +1 for mentioning that the random number must be uniformly distributed.

Answer (score 3):

That is **not** how goals are determined in FIFA or other video games.  They **don't** have a function that says, with some probability, the shot makes it or doesn't.

Rather, they simulate a ball actually being kicked into a goal.

The ball will have some speed *(based on the "shot power")* and some trajectory angle *(based on where the player aimed, and some variability based on the character's "shot skill")*.  Then they allow physics - and the AI of the goalee, if there is one - to take over, and count it as a point only when the ball physically enters the goal.

There is of course still randomness *involved*, but there is no single variable that decides whether or not a shot will make it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure but one way i would achieve:

Generate a random number (between 0 and 100). If the number is 89 or greater than return 1, elsewise return 0.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a random number generator, then you would do something like:

```
bool return_true_89_out_of_100() {
   double random_n = rand(); // returns random between 0 and 89
   return (random_n < 0.89);
}
```

You can generate a crudely random number by, for example, sampling lower bits of the CPU clock or some mathematical tricks.

Answer (score 0):

You're tagged language agnostic, but the answer depends on what random number function(s) are available to you. Furthermore the accuracy may depend on how close to being truly random your generator is (generally they're not that close).

As to random number functions, there tend to be two kinds -- those which generate a number between 0 and 1, and those that generate a number between m and n. Each can be used to derive a percentage easily.